# How do I query an API latency Error Budget from Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I have a Prometheus histogram, `api_response_duration_seconds`, of which I have an SLO defined as

```
histogram_quantile(0.95, sum(increase(api_response_duration_seconds_bucket[1m])) by (le)) <= 0.5
```

**Is there an easy way for me to query how large part ofthe past 28 days (in percentages) that this query has failed?** That is, I want to be able to answer "Has this query failed for more than 0.1% of the time for the past 28 days?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the secret here is that I want to convert a range vector to a range vector. This [isn't possible in Prometheus, but the workaround is to use a recording rule](https://www.robustperception.io/composing-range-vector-functions-in-promql).

So, what needs to be done is this:

```
groups:
  - name: SLOs
  - rules:
    - record: slo:api_response_duration_seconds:failing
      expr: histogram_quantile(0.95, sum(increase(api_response_duration_seconds_bucket[1m])) by (le)) > 0.5
    - record: slo:api_response_duration_seconds:all
      expr: histogram_quantile(0.95, sum(increase(api_response_duration_seconds_bucket[1m])) by (le))
```

and then query the error budget as

```
count_over_time(slo:api_response_duration_seconds:failing[28d])
/
count_over_time(slo:api_response_duration_seconds:all[28d])
```